# Kitchen experiment with a laser distance meter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, laser, diffraction

I'm performing a kitchen experiment where a knife's blade is placed in the path of a laser distance meter(red light).

At a distance of around 40cm I'm able to get distance readings that are smaller by around 10mm when a knife blade is placed in the laser beam. It also doesn't matter where in the beam the blade is placed - it always around 10mm(so reflections off the blade probably is not the reason).

At longer distances(e.g. 1m) the distance readings are stable(probably because of light loss due to diffraction), so it looks like the "particle light"(as in single slit) is faster than "wave light".

Coincidentally distance between laser and detector on the device is about 12mm (so the same magnitude as for observed effect).

Any explanations what could cause the observed effect?

Comment: When you say you are getting "distance readings that are smaller by around 10mm," what are you comparing? What measurement is 10mm longer than the knife measurement?

Comment: @MarkH Distance reading without knife blade is 10mm longer than distance reading with knife blade.

Comment: What distance are you measuring without the knife blade? What is the laser reflecting off of and where is it with respect to where the knife is placed? Photographs of your measurement setup will be a great help here.